# Can't chmod a Windows mounted folder in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, acl, setfacl

So I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a virtual machine inside Windows 10. A program on Ubuntu needs to have read and write permissions for a folder I mounted via VirtualBox, so I decided to try to chmod the folder. I understand that I can't do that, and have tried `sudo setfacl -m /path/to/dir`, and got this error: `setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 1`. Next, I tried `sudo setfacl -m u:user:rwx /path/to/dir`, and got this error: `setfacl: /path/to/dir/: Operation not supported`.

I honestly don't know what else to do, these commands are supposed to be correct but they won't work. Am I doing this wrong? Is there another way to do this? I was thinking of just mounting the hard drive on Linux, but I forgot Linux is just a virtual machine so that won't work, and dual booting is not an option for me.

Comment: Why do you need chmod. If you want just to be able to read and write shared folder, you should add your username to vboxsf group. That should help you access shared folder data. https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox

Comment: Microsoft formatted partitions do not support Linux ownership & permissions. Only how you mount the partition is the default. And Windows fast start up must be off as it sets hibernation flag. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 2):

The first `setfacl` is wrong. As for the rest `acl`s and Unix modes, are not supported on MS file-systems. Change the permission on the host.

Comment: Could you explain more about changing the permission on the host? I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: @botnewb Sorry that is an MS-Windows question. I don't know ether. From what I remember there is a read-only bit (this is a not-write bit). Then there is a very complex ACL system.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer!

Since my program had a user, I just added that user to the `vboxsf` group and solved my problem. No need for `chmod`.